# How can I concatenate an ArrayList<String> to another String?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, concatenation

I have a State class with these fields

```
String name;
City capital;
ArrayList<String> neighbors;
```

I have a toString() method

```
public String toString(){
    return ("new State(" + 
        this.name  + ", " + 
        this.capital + ", " + 
        this.neighbors + ")\n");
}
```

I am trying to test this method on the state

```
State ME = new State("ME", augusta, MEneighbors );
```

Where augusta is a defined City, and MEneighbors is an ArrayList with

```
MEneighbors.add("NH");
```

This is my test so far

```
t.checkExpect(ME.toString(),
    "new State(ME, " + augusta.toString() + ", " + [NH] + ")");
```

I don't quite understand why this isn't working. It works until the ArrayList MEneighbors. How can I get it to add the ArrayList as a String?

Many thanks.

Comment: Does this even compile?

Comment: How is it not working?  Are you getting incorrect output?  An exception message?

Comment: `+ [NH] +` This will never compile in this world.

Comment: is ArrayList's default .toString() not sufficient?

Comment: + [NH] + doesn't compile, what are you trying to do

Answer (score 2):

Even if you fix the code to be:

```
t.checkExpect(ME.toString(),
    "new State(ME, " + augusta.toString() + ", " + "[NH]" + ")");
```

Note: quotes around brackets.

You still forget to add the "\n" in the right side! Because your toString method adds "\n" in the end!

Answer (score 0):

When you define the toString method, call the [toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString%28%29) method for ArrayList, like this

```
public String toString(){
return ("new State(" + 
    this.name  + ", " + 
    this.capital + ", " + 
    this.neighbors.toString() + ")\n");
}
```

the `toString` method

```
Returns a string representation of this collection. The string representation consists of 
a list of the collection's elements in the order they are returned by its iterator, 
enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", "
(comma and space). Elements are converted to strings as by String.valueOf(Object).
```